# How to delete camel streaming file when size exceeds

Tags: java, apache-camel, locking, truncate

I want to delete a camel streaming file when its size exceeds the limit. I tried several options like,

1. roll file and then try to delete it, truncate the file.
2. rename the file to another one and create a file with the same name and delete the renamed file.
3. Acquire a lock and then delete it.

None of the above helped. Is this because the streaming file is locked by camel?

How do I go about achieving this? I am new to camel and not sure if Camel itself provides a way to do this.

Comment: What components are you using in your pattern?

Comment: I have used stream and file in separate routes. One route will stream the log events from sourceFile to destFile in remote server and second route will send the filepath to a bean which will try to truncate the file when sourceFile size exceeds the limit. I have written a sample program which will stream the file and try to truncate it, but the truncation doesn't work properly

Comment: You need to show what you actually do, show some code and tell us which version of Camel you use.

Comment: I need to stream three log files and truncate the same when its size exceeds. Here are the details:

`from("stream:file?scanStream=true&fileName=" + filePath).to("bean:myBean?method=remoteLog");` // to stream
`from("file:"+logFolder+"?include=^[A-Za-z0-9-_\\s\\.]*\\.log").to("bean:fileProcessor?method=makeSpace"); `// passes file to truncate.

I am now getting FailedToStartRouteException  because multiple consumer for the same endpoint is not allowed as the files passed in both routes are same. I am using camel 2.20.1